# How to create a function to remove specific dataframe rows according to a predefined parameter in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement

I have the following dataframe in order to study the covered distances of a fish on the seabed over one year:

```
StartPosition           FinishPosition      PathDistance        Time           Date
(27777.9, 1944.72)    (2783.63, 1941.08)        6.72            13:28:15.56    2023-07-08
(2783.63, 1941.08)    (2790.62, 1939.07)        3.22            14:12:19.52    2023-07-08
(2790.62, 1939.07)    (2778.02, 1946.28)        5.14            14:55:17.23    2023-07-08
(2778.02, 1946.28)    (2783.53, 1943.08)        7.60            15:33:47.27    2023-07-08
(2783.53, 1943.08)    (2792.62, 1963.25)        80.21           15:59:23.51    2023-07-08
(2792.62, 1963.25)    (2785.83, 1947.77)        2.96            16:31:12.14    2023-07-08
(2785.83, 1947.77)    (2756.21, 1933.54)        5.29            18:29:13.35    2023-07-08
(2756.21, 1933.54)    (2784.73, 1996.91)        105.32          19:01:45.35    2023-07-08
```

Before doing any analysis, I have to filter my dataframe from outlayers. For example, it is impossible for the analysed fish to travel more than 50 metres in 20 minutes, so these values should be removed.

Thus, i would like to create a function to run through the integrity of my dataframe and eliminate the wrong values according to a predefined time interval. For example, if the interval time between two consecutive points is < 15 min and the PathDistance(m) is > 50, i would eliminate the entire row.

Something like that (i hope it's not too bad!!):

```
def Filtr (IntervalTime, PathDistance):
    time1 = (df.iloc[i]['Time'])
    time2 = (df.iloc[i+1]['Time'])
    IntervalTime = time2 - time1
    if(IntervalTime > 15, PathDistance < 50):
        #maintain the row
    else:
        #remove the row
```

Sorry for the script, but i'm still a beginner in python!

##################################

Maybe a `for loop` like this is better, but i still miss something:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    time1 = (df.iloc[i]['Time'])
    time2 = (df.iloc[i+1]['Time'])
    IntervalTime = time2 - time1
    PathDistance = (row['PathDistance'])
    if IntervalTime < 30 and PathDistance > 100:
        distances.drop([row])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use `df.shift(1)` this will shift your data down by one, you can also do `df.shift(-1)` if you want to shift your data up by one.  Once you did that you can use numpy's where function to filter out the double condition.

```py
import numpy as np
df['time_difference'] = df['Time'] - df['Time'].shift(1)
distance_filter = df['PathDistance'] > 50
time_filter = df['time_difference'] < '15:00:00'

df['outlier'] = np.where( distance_filter & time_filter, 1, 0)
outlier_filter = df['outlier'] != 1
df = df[ outlier_filter ]
```

[image]